# How to resolve unmarshalling error after JBOSS EAP server migration from 6.4 to 7.4.3?

Tags: jboss, cxf, jboss7.x, jboss6.x, saxparser

I am trying to migrate my application server (JBOSS EAP) from 6.4 to 7.4.3. But, after migration I am getting the below error while hitting my webservices.

> Unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling error:
> unexpected element (uri: ....) Caused by :
> com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; line number: 0; columnNumber: 0;
> unexpected element (uri:....)

The same request was working absolutely fine in JBOSS EAP 6.4. But it is not working now after migration. I want to solve this without touching the codebase (means from server side - server config or server VM arguments etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following system property?

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.bind.backupWithParentNamespace=true
```

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis Chavariotis Sir, great answer! It worked. But, after adding the above system property only the below two lines are missing in my new JBOSS webservice response.  First Line - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>  and Second Line - <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV=...>But this two lines were present in JBOSS 6.4 response. Should I need to add any other system property for this. Please help.

Comment: Hello Panagiotis Chavariotis Sir, I am still facing the same issue as mentioned in my above comment. Could you please answer this. @mention https://stackoverflow.com/users/4456934/panagiotis-chavariotis Thanks!